# Javascript Converting Data syntax - Removing Quotes

Tags: javascript

I am converting some data for some charts that I'm using.

The data that the charts can read need to look like this:

```
[[1423008000000,1],[1423094400000,1],[1425513600000,42]]
```

The data that I have to convert looks like this:

```
{"1300752000000":11,"1301356800000":4,"1329782400000":22}
```

I then use this code to convert it:

```
$.getJSON('myurl', function(mydata) {

    var data = mydata;
    var res = Object.keys(data).map(itm => [itm, data[itm]]);
    var converted_data = res;
```

converted_data then gives my this:

```
[["1300752000000", 11], ["1301356800000", 4], ["1329782400000", 22]]
```

The converted data is adding " " - Quotes .... I need it to look like this:

```
[[1300752000000, 11], [1301356800000, 4], [1329782400000, 22]]
```

How can I get this converting code to convert without the quotes?

Comment: Replace [itm, data[itm]] by [Number(itm), data[itm]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object key's are *always* strings. You therefore need to cast `itm` to a number. Either by;

```
var res = Object.keys(data).map(itm => [+itm, data[itm]]);
```

... or more explicitly;

```
var res = Object.keys(data).map(itm => [Number(itm), data[itm]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace that like this:

```
[Number(itm), data[itm]]
```